# Which one is better between TextView or WebView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I'm about to display `HTML` data into my application with **fragment**. I'm confused of which one I need to use to get better performance between `TextView` or `WebView`. I mean, for rendering speed and memory issue.

Know that `Html.fromHtml()` is available for `TextView` to display `HTML` formatted data but I want to try `WebView` instead of `TextView`. But don't know rendering speed and memory issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WebView` internally provides different functionality for the display **Html** data. Also you can use `JavaScript` in `WebView`.

While `TextView` when you are use `Html.fromHtml()` then its **support only few Html tags**.
So I think its better to use **WebView**.

I just mentioned JavaScript functionality but There are other functionality like (Zoom Functionality, Image from web, etc..) All supports in WebView.

Answer (score 2):

depends for what you wish to use it.. if you are loading website and want all the features of that website to be available you should use webview. If you are only displaying one html snippet you should use textview