# Is that a good practice to use WebView instead of Textview?

Tags: android, webview, textview, text-formatting

I'm developing a android app and all contents are need to access locally i.e. app does not need internet connection. App is having static contents only. I have already developed app that can access html pages which i have stored locally in assets folder. I just want to Know that using `webview` for text formatting is good(general) practice or there is any other way to format text in android? as i know text formatting is somewhat tedious task in android. one more thing app will be in marathi language only. so please tell me any other way to format `textview` that can look good.

following is code for `webview`

```
public class AndroidHTMLActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myBrowser;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

    }
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/mybrowser" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: WebView seems like a bit of overkill for formatting text. It will format your text, but it will also add in a lot of functionality that will be nothing more than bulk code. What kind of formatting do you need to do? Formatting TextViews in fairly simple ways (font typeface, size, color, style) is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Including web view not so good practice, Instead you can use some of html tags in text view,.Please have a look at this http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html

Comment: Thank You answer..But why it is not good practice?? my app does not have lots of contents only I need some text formating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: it depends :)

Ask yourself the following questions:

- What kind of formatting do you want to apply?
- Is your text going to change?
- What kind of source are you going to use for the text?

Now the explanation: If you want to apply a simple formatting (e.g: bold, italic, some color) the `TextView` is your choice. It is simple and does the job. The problem comes when you want to do more complex formatting like paragraphs, indentations, etc.

A certain situation where you won't be able to cope with the `TextView` is when your text is going to be changed. I mean the following - you have a simple text that has two paragraphs. You can do this with `TextViews` with no effort - two `TextView`s with the proper layoutting, right? OK, but what happens if your text is loaded from the internet or a database or an external file and the updated version contains three paragraphs? Now you know what I mean :) In such cases it is better to use ```WebView`` because the data holds the formatting within itself.

Another case where the `WebView` is the better approach is when you want to show some rich text that is generated by external tool. For example if you have a `doc` file that you want to show in your app, you can convert it to `html` (there are a bunch of free online tools that do this) and then you can easily show it using `WebView` keeping all the formatting, colors, paragraphs, images, tables, etc. as they are.

The conclusion: For simple cases the `TextView` is the preferred approach because of its simplicity but for more complex cases or when your data is going to change its format, I recommend the `WebView`

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: Hey Kiril Nice Answer.. But what if my text is not change and i want some rich text in my andriod app..??

Comment: Hi @AnupChaudhary, it depends on how "rich" do you want it to be. You can make it rich using ```html``` and load it with ```WebView```. This way you can easily add tables, borders, paragrpahs, images, etc. If you just want to use bold style, one paragraph and an image, you can use ```TextView``` and an ```ImageView```.

Comment: Thank So much nice answer.. i'll use Webview

Comment: Glad to read that I helped you :)

Comment: Yes U help me..and people on stack always helps each other..

Comment: can u get me out of this? i want to start first activity for 5 sec only how cloud this possible in android? if any article is there plz suggest me

Answer (score 3):

WebView internally provides different functionality for the display Html data. Also you can use JavaScript in WebView.

While TextView when you use Html.fromHtml(), it supports only few Html tags. So I think its better to use WebView.

for more detail check this link as well

[Which one is better between TextView or WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858055/which-one-is-better-between-textview-or-webview)

Comment: Ok thank for answer.. I'll wait for more answer but thank you man...

Comment: After browsing around, i would agree with @Adan Ali. I consider a textView for just plain text and not really markup. The WebView was designed specifically for web markup i.e. html. Thus, i would use a WebView. Also consider the fact that if you decide to enhance your app and add javascript to the webpage, all the plumbing is already done for you. That's my 2 cents on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

TextView doesn't support indentation and alignment, so if you need that, you must go with WebView. If you just need some simple html formatting, then TextView is faster.